# Foreach repeat twice a single iteration

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$fruits = array('apple', 'strawberry', 'orange', 'peach');
```

This is my code to cycle it:

```
foreach( $fruits as $key => $fruit ) {
    if( $key == 1 ) {
        echo "ADV";
    }
    else {
        echo $fruit;
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
apple
ADV
orange
peach
```

How can I change my code in order to have this result?

```
apple
ADV
strawberry
orange
peach
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the else block and echo all fruits

Comment: :D no worries, mind can get stuck with silly things sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach( $fruits as $key => $fruit ) {
    if( $key == 1 ) {
        echo "ADV";
    }
    echo $fruit;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Please try :**

```
$fruits = array('apple', 'strawberry', 'orange', 'peach'); 
$inserted = array( 'ADV' ); // Not necessarily an array
array_splice( $fruits, 1, 0, $inserted ); 

foreach( $fruits as $key => $fruit ) {
        echo $fruit;

}
```